# Spring SPEL : setRemoteDirecotoryExpression issue

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

I'm trying to set the remote directory for my SFTP server using Java Spring's SPEL language. Basically I'm trying to append two strings together as my remote directory path, but for some reason I'm still trying to figure out, it does not work.
Here's what I do :

```java
ExpressionParser EXPRESSION_PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression("headers['path']"); //which contains the 2nd part of the path to my dir
String fullFilePath = this.remoteDir; //which has the 1st part of the path to my directory
SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString(this.remoteDir.concat("/").concat(exp.getValue().toString()));
handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
```

There is seemingly something wrong with the `exp.getValue()`method, because I get the following exception whenever that line is not commented :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SFTPConfig' defined in file [/Users/psdev/PrediSurge/backend/file-service/target/classes/com/predisurge/planopsuite/microservices/fileservice/sftp/SFTPConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handler' defined in class path resource [com/predisurge/planopsuite/microservices/fileservice/sftp/SFTPConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'SFTPConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'handler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.predisurge.planopsuite.microservices.fileservice.FileServiceApplication.main(FileServiceApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handler' defined in class path resource [com/predisurge/planopsuite/microservices/fileservice/sftp/SFTPConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'SFTPConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'handler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.resolveTargetBeanFromMethodWithBeanAnnotation(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:464) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:146) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.processAnnotationTypeOnMethod(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:190) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$0(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:589) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:144) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:434) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1749) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'SFTPConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'handler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213) ~[spring-expression-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:53) ~[spring-expression-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:89) ~[spring-expression-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:109) ~[spring-expression-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:138) ~[spring-expression-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.predisurge.planopsuite.microservices.fileservice.sftp.SFTPConfig.handler(SFTPConfig.java:101) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

I'm not new to Java Spring but I've never used SPEL before, so I'm very unsure what's wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString(this.remoteDir.concat("/").concat(exp.getValue().toString()));`

The expression has to be evaluated at runtime against a messagee, you are evaluating the expression during configuration time against nothing.

Use

```
"'" + this.remoteDir + "/' + headers['path']"
```

so the `headers['path']` is evaluated against the message sent to the handler.

Comment: You need single quotes around the literal part.

Comment: So basically, the way I wrote that line you highlighted , the ```exp.getValue()``` was always going to be an issue because it didn't have a value before running time ?

Comment: Right; expressions are evaluated against some `root` object (the `Message<?>` sent to the handler in this case - equivalent to `message.getHeaders().get("path")` in java). Your code was evaluating it too early, with no root object (hence `Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on null`).

Answer (score 0):

The EL expression "headers['path']" probably refers to a map, containing key "path". By default spring expression parser has no information about external variables. You should create an instance of StandardEvaluationContext, register the variable "headers" there and use this context, when getting expression value:

```
ExpressionParser EXPRESSION_PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser();

// create context and register variable "headers"
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.setVariable("headers",headers);

Expression exp = EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression("headers['path']"); 
String fullFilePath = this.remoteDir; 
SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());

// use context, when getting evaluated value
 handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString(this.remoteDir.concat("/").concat(exp.getValue(context).toString()));
        handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
```

Here is a [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-variables) for using variables in spring EL.

Comment: Strictly speaking, in this case the variable `headers` would be referred to as `#headers` in the expression. `headers` with no `#` refers to the `root` object - either specified in the evaluation context or in a `getValue(root, ...)` variant.